# Forking a project, how to change header info ? How goes copyright in merging changes?

Tags: header, merge, fork

I want to create a fork of a big opensource library/software. My intention is not to go a different rout, or to change fundamentals of the software, but to add functionality I need in projects and follow the upstream distribution closely. .. but every source file of the library comes with a big fat header:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
  =========                 |
  \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
   \\    /   O peration     |
    \\  /    A nd           | Copyright (C) 2009-2011 OpenCFD Ltd.
     \\/     M anipulation  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
and goes on on on....
```

I know I have to keep the copyright of the original developer. Can I change the header ?? To something  more compact like:

```
/* New Project - new project description
   Licensed under GPL v3
   Copyright (c) 2011-X My company
   Copyright (c) 2009-2011 OpenCFD Ltd.*/
```

If so.. how do I proceed when I want to merge new modifications from the upstream developer ??

If someone with experience on the matter could help, it would be wonderful! Thanks

Comment: Read the license, or have your lawyer read the license. If it says you can't redistribute without the header, then don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is only to add functionality, why would you fork at all? They have git repository, clone it, and apply your patches/code on top of it. Your new files will have the headers you want. On modified one, I would leave it as is, and just add my copyright note for the changes.

And who knows, maybe if there are enough users for the additions you make, these changes can find their way back in the upstream.

Read the article [To Fork or Not To Fork](http://mako.cc/writing/to_fork_or_not_to_fork.html) has some very interesting points.

Comment: The upstream developer usually don't merge back.. they are a little closed to extern contributions. They also have an disclaimer about the name of the project, that is also a trademark. So I canno't change it and keep the name of the original.

Comment: And you don't change the name. You just open your cloned repo with the changes you make. As I said, if there's use of your changes, and they do not interfere with the roadmap the upstream set, the demand will require the changes to be accepted back. Usually forking is an option if there's a difference in the roadmap view, and if in a long run it's obvious that the projects will go in very different directions, or if the upstream does not actively work on the project any more, but does not allow anyone else to step in. From what you said, it's not the case.

Comment: Rigth.. And how do you would "just add my copyright note for the changes" ?? At the commit message ?